# My images aren't loading, no matter what I tried, it doesn't work, so can anyone find a possible solution?

Tags: html, image, url

I want to make images on a test website, I tried everything and it doesn't work. Firsty, I tried with a url from the net with a image with a src from the web. Next, I tried downloading the image and getting it from my folders, but it still didn't load.

```
<img src= "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tripadvisor.ca%2FLocationPhotoDirectLink-g154943-d1554681-i285077022-Rocky_Mountaineer-Vancouver_British_Columbia.html&psig=AOvVaw2ixiY9iFgigzy5YdLP0ujd&ust=1586461552690000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMCGvI_M2egCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAO" alt="Pic">
```

```
<img src= "beautiful-scenery.jpeg" alt="Pic">
```

They didn't work.

*By the way, I am 12, so like don't blame me if I'm done. :)*

Comment: i meant dumb yeah

Answer (score 0):

lets focus on local file.

First, double check that beautiful-scenery.jpeg is located next to the html file and that it has the same name and extension(it could be jpg).

Second, remove this whitespace between src= and ", like so:

```
<img src="beautiful-scenery.jpeg" alt="Pic">
```

Follow up question: How do you run your html file?

Comment: I'm not actually making a website, just testing how some html and css works. I use sublime text, and then I go to the file, right click and press open with chrome

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using in the src tag does not point to an image.

Check https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp to learn all about images in HTML.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Pic">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thhe thing the url worked for me in google, it did go to an image. So I tried it again today but it somehow worked. Thanks anyways